# Display Message for cells missing text

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a cell (A11) that should have various text and another cell (B11) that should have various text. I need a message (INPUT VARIABLE MISSING) to display in a cell (J11) if either A11 or B11 are missing text or no message to display if both cells contain text.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? We're not a VBA/script writing service. Please refer to the tour pages here https://superuser.com/tour particularly https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sounds like homework?

Answer (score 0):

A simple if combined with an or should do the trick:

```
=IF(OR(A11="",B11=""),"(INPUT VARIABLE MISSING)","")
```

For me, this returns a blank cell when A11 and B11 are anything other than empty, and the message "(INPUT VARIABLE MISSING)" if either is blank.

Comment: Thanks for the help. What if I have a range of cells I am checking and I want the message to appear in one cell? Like if I want to check cells A11 - A 89 and B11 - B89 and want the message to appear in cell K11...how would that work? I tried using colons like in certain functions (A11:A89) but that did not work. Thanks.